# How to make Facebook defaults the viewer video in HD

Tags: facebook

On Facebook, some videos are with HD enabled automatically by default, while others are not. I uploaded some videos, and would like that my viewers see it with HD turned on by default.
I want my facebook videos playing in HD without requesting the user to change his video settings.

Facebook seems to play my videos in SD. Why does it happen? How to configure it to HD? What is the secret? Is there any option/payment to enable it by default?

1) For example, [this video](https://www.facebook.com/video.php?v=10151554502361159) is HD but  only plays in HD if user clicks on HD button.
2) But on [this video](https://www.facebook.com/video.php?v=10152663952345769) it plays by default on HD without user need to click on HD button.

My video playing settings are facebook default setting. My download speed is about 14 Mbps.

I would like to enable this HD by default, without the user change his video settings.
I want my video playing in HD as the video on that second [link](https://www.facebook.com/video.php?v=10152663952345769).

Answer (score 2):

If your facebook settings are set to play video by default quality, then the videos get played sometimes in HD and sometimes not. For videos one minute or longer, usually the videos get played to SD, less than one minute, they get played in HD. But if your connection (or server you are in) is fast enough, the videos get played in HD even for longer videos.
 *[Someone correct me if I'm wrong, since I have come to this conclusion by making different tests myself.]* 
In case you want to watch your videos always in SD or always in HD, you can change that at your facebook settings. Go to the top-right corner of your facebook page, click on the little down arrow, and go to settings. On the left, go to videos (the bottom on the list). The first one is "Video Default Quality", select SD to play all videos in SD (HD disabled), or HD to play all of them in HD.

Comment: usually if you have a connection of 6 Mbits or faster, videos get played always in HD.

Comment: My connection is about 14 Mbps, but my own videos play SD for me, while the video mentioned on the second link plays HD. There is some hidden feature/secret to enable this HD by default, without the user change his video settings

Comment: +1 for this detail: "less than one minute, they get played in HD." I downloaded a video that was being displayed in HD, uploaded to my timeline, and the video played in SD.

Comment: I checked this https://www.facebook.com/video.php?v=10152663952345769 it is more than a minute and is defaulted to HD.

Comment: I'm not quite sure then. But as I said, it could be the server you are in also. Or how much traffic is at that moment on that facebook server. Facebook hasn't made clear anything about video playback. They add the video settings and then remove it, and add it again. Maybe they are still working on it.For example, last night when I checked the 'video setting' was there, today it's not.

Answer (score 1):

After some trial and error I believe the only solution is to adjust the render settings of your videos before uploading them to Facebook.

Below are the render settings that I've begun using.

```
H.264 Codec
Progressive

VBR, 2 pass
Target bit rate = 5
Max bit rate =10

Frame size = 1920 x 1080
Frame rate = 29.97fps

AAC, 192 kbps
44.1 Hz, Stereo
```

My videos now default to HD as long as the viewer's internet connection is fast enough, regardless of whether the video is hosted on Facebook.com, is embedded on a website, or is being viewed by someone without a Facebook account.

I posed a similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44247352/force-facebook-videos-embedded-in-a-website-default-to-hd/44250360#44250360) and the above render settings still appear to be the best solution.

Comment: What did you use to render using those settings? I'm using iMovie which doesn't appear to provide that level of control.

Comment: I used Adobe Premier CS5 on Windows 7. I believe that it's possible to get a free trial of the latest version of Adobe Premier to see if it has the settings that you need.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I can tell, it might have something to do with the Facebook profile page. Maybe Facebook is playing favorites?

If you go to any of the HD videos on this page, they seem to default to playing in HD (even if you have your fb settings to play 'default'):
https://www.facebook.com/stephaniesid/videos

But if you go to any of the HD videos on this page, they default to playing in standard!:
https://www.facebook.com/jonathanscalesfourchestra/videos

Also, the same *exact* video was uploaded to both of those accounts to test, and it showed in HD on the first one and standard on the second!

I'm confused.

Comment: Please don't comment as an answer. For more information, please see [Why do I need 50 reputation to comment? What can I do instead?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/214173/21960) However, I think this provides some clues and is at least a partial answer. It should stay.